# Need to catch <select> change event, when it changes programmatically

Tags: jquery, events

I have a select on a page, which is transformed into slider using [Filament's Group selectToUISlider](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/update_jquery_ui_16_slider_from_a_select_element/).

Another script on a page is attached to onchange events of the form elements. Every time user changes something, it recalculates the result.

Now here's the problem - `onChange` event doesn't fire for `<select>` when you use the slider, since `<select>` value is changed using plugin.

Here's the fiddle to illustrate the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/t3aMe/

Is there a way to monitor a change in `selectedIndex` of a select? Or maybe there's a way to plug into `jQuery.val()` function to make it `trigger('change')`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you could overwrite the `val` function:

```
(function ($) {
  var val = jQuery.fn.val;

  jQuery.fn.val = function () {
    var result = val.apply(this, arguments);

    if (arguments.length) {  // e.g if this is a "set" rather than a get
      this.filter('select').trigger('change');
    };

    return result;
  };
}(jQuery));
```

This will trigger the `change` event for alll select elements in the page, though. You could add a massive hack:

```
if (arguments.length) {  // e.g if this is a "set" rather than a get
  this.filter('select#select_test').trigger('change');
};
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/t3aMe/2/

Comment: Hey, Matt, your solution is great. Didn't think it would be that simple to "extend" `.val()`

Answer (score 1):

Just trigger change event on select element:

```
$('#select_test').trigger('change');
```

In your example code:

```
(function($) {
    $('#select_test').change(function() {
        $('#debug').text('onChange: new value: ' + $(this).val());
    });

    $('#change_select').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var newv = parseInt($('#select_test').val()) + 1;
        $('#select_test').val(newv > 3 ? newv - 3: newv);

        $('#select_test').trigger('change');
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Yeah, I know about `.trigger()`, the problem is that `.val()` is called inside a plugin, I am looking for a solution that does not require me to modify it.

Comment: I see, I think that you best option is to modify the plugin. Or you could override jquery val like second answer from Matt.